# Radial capacitor marking

Tags: capacitor, markings

I have radial capacitors with markings *235 RCN* on one side and *333 C5K* on the other side. How do I interpret these?

Front side:

[image]

Back side:

[image]

Comment: 33 nF? C could be a voltage designator.

Comment: Photo, please...

Comment: Please add a photo of the capacitor.

Comment: [You have a part intended to be used in a Republic of Cinnabar Navy starship.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCN_Series)  235 is the RCN purchase order number used when that batch was ordered.

Comment: @DwayneReid Added

Comment: 33 nF. The "k" is the tolerance. You will have to look that up - I **think** it is 10% but I'm not positive. "J" is 5%, though. No clue what the voltage rating is, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

333 = 33*10^3  pF = 33 nF

235 RCN is MFG date code and factory code for traceability

e.g. 23rd week of 2015

RCN could mean any location, unique for each OEM.

Comment: The capacitor has both markings, one on each side. It cannot have two different values.

Comment: "YOu have capacitors" was ambiguous then

Answer (score 3):

It is a AVX capacitor: 333 - 33nF, C5K - X7R 50V +/-10%

[image: marking]

Link to datasheet:
http://datasheets.avx.com/SR-Series.pdf